# Update more record in one query with Active Record in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

Is there a better way to update more record in one query with different values in Ruby on Rails? I solved using CASE in SQL, but is there any Active Record solution for that?

Basically I save a new sort order when a new list arrive back from a jquery ajax post.

```
#List of product ids in sorted order. Get from jqueryui sortable plugin.
#product_ids = [3,1,2,4,7,6,5]

# Simple solution which generate a loads of queries. Working but slow.
#product_ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
#  Product.where(id: id).update_all(sort_order: index+1)
#end

##CASE syntax example:
##Product.where(id: product_ids).update_all("sort_order = CASE id WHEN 539 THEN 1 WHEN 540 THEN 2 WHEN 542 THEN 3 END")

case_string = "sort_order = CASE id "      

product_ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
  case_string += "WHEN #{id} THEN #{index+1} "
end

case_string += "END"

Product.where(id: product_ids).update_all(case_string)
```

This solution works fast and only one query, but I create a query string like in php. :) What would be your suggestion?

Comment: Whats the size of your tables, you really want **one** query? i think either your choose for easier to read, and have multiple queries, or you have one query and it gets a bit more messy. Depending on how often this query is done (and how indexes are set),  i think multiple queries should be fine.

Comment: Rogier, thanks for your comment. You are right. I agree with you. If I have a list of 20 elements, with 20 queries, it takes 100-150ms, so no big deal. But one query takes only 2ms and I get the same results. Of course in this case, probably not really need that, but would be great to know a general concept for making databases faster with less query. :)

Comment: Am I right that with your approach, if you change the order of two products, you need to change the sort order for every product (ie row) in your table (or at least every row 'between' the 2 products), and thus as your product table grows the number of row updates grows also? In which case, why not consider a new table that simply holds the comma-delimited string of sorted ids? Read it before displaying products, update it after a re-order?

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the acts_as_list gem. It does everything you need and it uses 1-3 queries behind the scenes. Its a perfect match to use with jquery sortable plugin. It relies on incrementing/decrementing the position (sort_order) field directly in SQL.

This won't be a good solution for you, if your UI/UX relies on saving the order manually by the user (user sorts out the things and then clicks update/save). However I strongly discourage this kind of interface, unless there is a specific reason (for example you cannot have intermediate state in database between old and new order, because something else depends on that order).

If thats not the case, then by all means just do an asynchronous update after user moves one element (and acts_as_list will be great to help you accomplish that).

Check out:

https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/blob/master/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb#L324

```
# This has the effect of moving all the higher items down one.
def increment_positions_on_higher_items
  return unless in_list?
  acts_as_list_class.unscoped.where(
    "#{scope_condition} AND #{position_column} < #{send(position_column).to_i}"
  ).update_all(
    "#{position_column} = (#{position_column} + 1)"
  )
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks promising. I definitely give it a try.